# EventKit RequestAccess not able to reset in iOS Simulator for testing

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, ios6, xamarin

I'm testing the new request access requirement for calendar (EventKit) integration in iOS 6.  The problem in testing is that once the prompt occurs it will never occur again, not even in the iOS simulator or deleting the app from the device.  There are other issues in the iOS simulator in that you never see an entry in Settings/Privacy/Calendars created so I can't verify the functionality in the sim.

Anyone know how to reset the access request system so I can view and test the prompt and various conditions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see where to reset them on the device (not sim) - go to Settings / General / Reset / Reset Location & Privacy and that works.

Thank you @poupou on the sim info.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reset the simulator itself. You can do so from the **iOS Simulator** menu and select **Reset Content and Settings...**

Note that will remove every application, data (and settings) for the currently executing version of the simulator.

OTOH that might not work as the privacy checks are incomplete on the simulator. From Apple [iOS6 SDK release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012166-CH1-SW19):

> Simulator
>
> - No privacy alerts are displayed in iOS Simulator for apps that access Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders.